# Proof of the distributive property of polynomials not clear to me.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, solution-verification

I have to study $(R[x],*,+)$ which is the ring of polynomials with its sum and product. 
When I had to study that multiplications distributes over addition I came up with this proof:
$ Let\ a(x), b(x), c(x) \in R[x]$ whose degree is $n$ for all of them.

$$c(x) * ( a(x) + b(x) )$$
$$= c(x) * \sum_{i=0}^{n}(a_i+b_i)*x^i$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{s+r=i}c_s * (a_r+b_r))x^i$$
which, by various properties equals
$$(\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{s+r=i}c_s a_r )x^i) + (\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{s+r=i}c_s b_r )x^i) $$
Which the book says it's the definition of $ (c(x)*a(x)) + (c(x)*b(x))$ but I have a doubt.
The $+$ in
$$(\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{s+r=i}c_s a_r )x^i) + (\sum_{i=0}^{2n}(\sum_{s+r=i}c_s b_r )x^i) $$
is $(R,+)$, 
while the $+$ in $$ (c(x)*a(x)) + (c(x)*b(x))$$ 
is $(R[x],+)$ 
So saying "it's the definition of" is false, or am I wrong? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Something is weird in your description because the expression "is the definition of" applies to a compound expression, for which a definition is certainly irrelevant. You should rephrase.

Comment: @yves-daoust thank you but I have no idea how to rephrase, it's written just like that. Furthermore, I found the exact same proof on another website (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Multiplication_of_Polynomials_Distributes_over_Addition) and they say the same thing.

Comment: You should not limit the discussion to polynomials of equal degree.

Comment: No, they are not saying the same thing, it is not "written like that". They are more specific about what is being defined.

Comment: Well, I think it's been done like that because if the three degrees are different, we can add $0$s to reach the "highest" degree of the three polynomials, it's written "without loss of generality" and I'd agree on that.

Comment: Provided you extend the concept of degree. This must be said explicitly. And I don't see a WLOG anywhere !

Comment: As long as you don't rephrase your question, it can't be answered.

Comment: I'd just like to prove that $*$ distributes over $+$ using any proof, so if you have in mind one if this is not correctly formuled, feel free to answer :)

Comment: You can expand the products with the separate polynomials and with the sum, then apply distributivity of the real product over real addition and associativity of addition. I can't figure out what you are missing.